# Installing wwWidgets for Qt 5

Tags: qt5, wwwidgets

I recently installed Qt 5.0.2 with MinGW 4.7. Previously I used Qt 4.8 and I used wwWidgets, a useful widget pack for my projects from http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/. When I installed this pack to Qt 5.0.2 it installs without errors but its plugins are not installed in the Qt Designer. If anyone successfully installed the package for Qt 5.0.2 please provide me with instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to compile Qt5, QT Creator & Plugins, wwWidgets from source, using the same options for all of them. Qt designer silently flushes plugins that are not compiled in the same manner than designer itsself.